# Improve performance of NGINX Server on a Worker Node

Tags: performance, nginx, docker

I have deployed 10 NGINX servers on a single worker node using Docker Services.

10 services 1 Machine- Each Service giving me X Performance.

When I remove 9 of the services, the performance of the one service remaining is still X.

1 Service 1 Machine - Still giving me same X performance.

Why isn't the performance of the service running improving upon me removing the other services?

I am testing my performance using  apache benchmark:'ab -n 1000 -c 10 ', looking at Requests per second. They always remain around 1200, whatsoever configuration of my Worker node I use.

Comment: This won't answer your question completely, but CPU sharing defaults to equal so originally you would have 10 containers vying for 1/10 of your CPU if they were all being hit at the same time.  However, that does not imply that they were all being utilized, if when you tested performance no other containers were doing anything it would be the same as just having one container.    Furthermore, this says nothing about how efficient your service actually is.

Comment: You should likely post how you are measuring performance and more details about what you are running.

Comment: I have added how I am Performance testing in my edit, also my service is a simple nginx server untouched from whats available as the image online.